# How to create a ldap user in wso2 identity server by using scim endpoints?

Tags: rest, ldap, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I have integrated ldap with wso2 IS and i could access ldap users from IS, But now i want to add a new user to ldap user store by using scim endpoints (in a RESTful way).pls help..

Comment: I guess.  This has been already discussed here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597290/wso2-identity-server-how-to-assign-an-existing-role-to-a-wso2-is-user?rq=1

Comment: It doesn't tell anything to add a new user to ldap user store, Whenever creating a new user with the curl command, It directly goes to the identity user store, Nothing added to ldap user store..

Comment: It means that you have configured two user stores?  Basically you have configured a LDAP user store with Identity Server. OK? then there is default user store that is shipped by Identity server.  User is created always in default user store...  then you need to qualify the user name with the domain name of the user store. ex- if user store domain name is "foo". Then user must be created with "foo/user1"

Comment: I have mapped the SCIM claims to the existing attributes of the Active Directory. Now i could add users to ldap with the following cURL command.
But its not working with the following curl command

curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"gunasinghe","givenName":"hasinitg"},"userName":'**ldap/hasinitg**',"password":"hasinitg","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"hasini_home.com","type":"home"},{"value":"hasini_work.com","type":"work"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users

Comment: "Errors":[{"description":"Error in adding the user: ldap/hasinitg to the user store..","code":"500"}]}*

Error in wso2 IS Console
ERROR org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint} -  Error in adding the us
er: ldap/hasinitg to the user store..
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Can not access the directory context or user already exists in the system

Comment: when you are using two use stores,  you need to map the attributes correctly using claim management. Following is the pattern....  {domainname/attributeName};{domainname/attributeName};  and so on..  but for default user store, you do not want to provide the domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a user to LDAP by using SCIM endpoints, we need to map SCIM claims to the LDAP attributes. For more information click [here](http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2013/06/scim-user-provisioning-with-wso2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this tutorial to begin with: http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/wso2-identity-server-as-scim-service.html

Comment: yes...I have already gone through the above mentioned article, It doesn't tell anything to add a new user to ldap store. Whenever im creating a new user, It directly goes to the identity user store.

Comment: In Identity Server "user store" is a level of abstraction provide to its users when managing users. Underlying physical user store can be in form like LDAP or JDBC.