# how to add users to roles using SCIM in WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to add roles to users programatically in WSO2 Identity server.
I am able to create users by SCIM API's.But cant find an API to add a user to a role.
I tried giving the user name as "userName":"role/myusername" in the wso2/scim/Users POST API. But its not working ; not sure if its the correct approach.
Can someone tell me how to add a role to an existing user and also add a role to a new user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19785784/2751640) shows how to do that with SCIM PUT command.

Also From IS 5.1.0 onwards you can also use the PATCH operation as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/SCIM+APIs)

> Add user AMRSNGHE/groupUSR001 to group AMRSNGHE/ngioletGR
>
> curl -k --user admin:admin -X PATCH -d '{"displayName": 'AMRSNGHE/ngioletGR',"members": [{"value":"","display": 'AMRSNGHE/groupUSR001'}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Groups/<id returned in the response when creating the group AMRSNGHE/ngioletGR>