# wso2is curl claims authorization

Tags: permissions, authorization, wso2-identity-server

I have spent a lot if time in the documentation and this Q/A forum but have still not ascertained the information I need/understand.  The model that I ham working with does not exactly meld with WSO2IS very well.  The programmer is set in their ways and will not budge on change, nothing I can do about that.  They are just after the security that is provided by WSO2IS.  So here is programmers model, NOT sso.
user->web_site->wso2is authorization->website
It is to have every user login every time.  What they want from wso2s is to send user_name, password and company_id and to return valid/invalid id and a set of permission. External id should work well as a claim for the company id.
I have been able to create a user, but not able to add a role for that user and I have not been able to get authorization.  I can get some of the information about the user via SCIM : curl -v -k --user admin:admin https://wso2-dev.h3net.com:9443/wso2/scim/Users/d9bef03a-ddcf-44fc-a431-3b71e618b61e
What I need are 3 curl commands via REST like commands
Here's what I have for adding a user : curl -k -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user":{"username":"Gomez","realm":"PRIMARY","password":"Password1!","claims":[{"uri":"http://wso2.org/claims/givenname","value":"Gomez"},{"uri":"http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress","value":"bnpatton@west.com"},{"uri":"http://wso2.org/claims/lastname","value":"Adams"},{"uri":"http://wso2.org/claims/mobile","value":"1234567890"}]},"properties":[]}' "https://wso2-dev.h3net.com:9443/api/identity/user/v0.9/me

This does not show haw to add a role for the user, just claims.
With something like the above, how would I do the following :
1. add roles to a user
2. authorize user when just only have user_name, password and company_id(external_id claim)
3. return permissions with authorization or a separate curl command?

Answer (score 0):

- Question 1

You can refer [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444103/how-to-add-users-to-roles-using-scim-in-wso2) for adding roles to the user using SCIM API.

- Question 2

In this case, you can use [XACML](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/XACML+Architecture) for claim based authorization. Please refer [this blog](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/11/claim-based-authorization-with-wso2.html) for the implementation.

- Question 3

WSO2IS server is working as policy decision point(PDP). Based on the decision you can access the resource in the resource server.